# Node.js exec() doesn't execute callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec, child-process

I have a simple method that executes `exec` method from `child_process` using `rm -rf` as command.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec

const Foo = {
  emptyDir: params => {
    exec(`rm -rf ${params.path}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log('test');
    })
  }
}

Foo.emptyDir({path:'./data/*'})
```

Method works and files do get deleted, however callback never gets executed. What am I missing?

> Node version: v6.10.2

Comment: It works , I have the same node version

Comment: @MahmoudEzzat Does it execute `console.log('test')` part?

Comment: Ok guys, I was running this inside other script and I had sync `process.exit()` below and it would not execute callback because `process.exit()` would kill it before callback would be executed. I edited question a bit, so it can be more helpful if someone comes across this question in future seeking solution to a real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you may want to use one of those modules to remove files in Node:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/remove
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf

Now, it's not possible that the `console.log('test');` is not executed, because you don't even test for errors so it will be executed even if you don't have the `rm` command in PATH or if it fails.

What is possible is that you may not see the `console.log()` output if the STDOUT is redirected or even the `console.log` redefined. To really see if the callback is called you may try to write some message to a file.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I've tried these modules and the problem was in the main script where I executed method, I had sync func `process.exit()` that would kill script before callback would be executed.

Comment: @Kunok don't call `process.exit()` yourself. You've just discovered one of the reasons why.

Comment: @AlexTes Yeah I rarely use it in production code. However I was just testing something in this script and I used `process.exit()` to prevent execution of other methods below. but I didn't think deep enough to notice it was actually faulting testcase.